# Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a site recently that is now coming up with jQuery errors!
It has been behaving fine until recently when I have noticed these errors in chromes console. These seem to be coming up within the google hosted jQuery. I've tried using previous versions of jQuery as well but it keeps showing the errors.

It's online at https://www.upsandgeneratorparts.com/auction/

the header file is http://pastebin.com/PiKigvhg

This is the error that is showing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
(anonymous function)
e.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
e.extend.each jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.append jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.html jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
e.extend.access jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.html jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.load.f.ajax.complete jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.Callbacks.o jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
w jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
```

Is there a way of using noconflict to sort this or another handy function or am i just missing something out completely!

Oliver

Answer (score 2):

You are using `noConflict` which sets `$` to `undefined`, hence it's no longer a function.

Do not use `.noConflict()` unless you are 110% sure of what you are doing. It's technically completely useless function.

Comment: Its technically very useful, if you say run prototype, or multiple version of jQuery.

Comment: @Petah technically you can just let prototype overwrite `$` without doing anything. As for running multiple versions of jQuery.... dear god why

Comment: The one time I have had to run multiple version of jQuery was to provide interoperability between my library, and someone else's old site. And you assume jQuery is loaded before prototype.

Comment: @Petah yes but technically you can load prototype after jQuery. That's what I mean by technically useless. Maybe I am using the wrong word. I want to say that in 99% of situations conflicts are from poorly encapsulated libraries and not magically solved by calling `.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use (which you are) `$.noConflict` you can no longer access the `$` object.

Hence, either don't use it, or always use the `jQuery` object instead of `$`.

On the source of the page you supplied I noticed this at line 737:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...
```

Comment: so if i removed all the use of $.noConflict and change all the jQuery. back to $. would this take it all back to normal?